# How to use not() in conjunction with 'and' in xpath

Tags: xpath

I have a scenario where I should select only those elements with color other than  rgb(170, 170, 170).

I'm trying to locate elements with the following xpath:

```
.//span[@class='box' and not(@style='background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170)')]
```

With this xpath firebug is selecting all of the elements including those I restricted with the not().

Comment: Could you post sample elements that was mistakenly selected by that XPath? Thanks

Comment: Show your HTML and realize that styles are not being calculated, just matched lexically.

Comment: @kjhughes There are several of elements with the following HTML and few of them with different rgb. So I wanted to locate only those with the rgb(170,170,170), Below is the HTML of one among them <span class="box" style="{'background-color': region.color}" style="background-color: rgb(170, 170, 170);"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely (as kjhughes pointed out) does you style attribute contain more styles than the `background-color`. To find your value any way you may use `contains()`.

```
(contains(@style,, 'background-color: rgb( 170, 170, 170)')
```

But now the formating may  still have different amount of spaces.
To avoid them you can use `translate()` To remove all spaces use:

```
translate(@style,' ','')
```

Therefore try:

```
//span[@class='box' and  not(contains(translate(@style,' ',''), 'background-color:rgb(170,170,170)') )]
```

Comment: It is working with the path you simplified by eliminating spaces. Thanks @hr_117